# How to show response from udp server using DatagramSocket.receive as string?

Tags: java, udp

I use `DatagramSocket` in android application. I am sending request from client to server. The server responds with a string value either 1 or 0 .
My code sample is as follow:

```
// client sends
socket.send(datagrampacket); 

//Server have
socket.receive (datagrampacket);
```

I am using Logging to display the response coming from the server, but i don't know how to show the server response (the string received 0 or 1).

after server responding .. 
how can i receive datagrampacket on client side (as string it might be 0 or 1) ?

Comment: Please restate your question in standard English. At present it is incomprehensible.

Comment: I have tried helping by formatting and made it readable. Hope that helps

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 2):

`socket.receive()` will block until it received data. the received data will be in the `datagrampacket` byte-array.

to display it, convert the byte-array to a string, e.g. in java this will look like:

```
byte[]data=datagrampacket.getData();
int offset=datagrampacket.getOffset();
int length=datagrampacket.getLenght();
System.out.println( new String(data, offset, length) ) ;
```

Comment: Wrong. You need to take into account the offset and length properties of the DatagramPacket.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the hint (and downvoting rather than providing a correct answer); i updated my answer